# Grouped product (simple product sorting on price) Magento 2

Tags: sorting, grouped-products, price-sorting

In Magento 2.2 on the **product view** page is it possible to **sort the simple products of a grouped product based on price** (or any other attribute)?

At the moment they seem to be sorting randomly.

*I know that you can change sort order when editing grouped product in admin panel, but this is not realistic when confronted with hundreds of products.*

Comment: you mean on listing page?

Comment: The product view page @Knight017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `public function getAssociatedProducts($product)` of this file:

> vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php

in this function you have to remove `setPositionOrder()` method on collection and have to set your required order.

```
public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
{
    if (!$product->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
        $associatedProducts = [];

        $this->setSaleableStatus($product);

        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection(
            $product
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            ['name', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id']
        )->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->getStoreFilter($product)
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'status',
            ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
        );

        /** this is new order of collection by name **/
        $collection->setOrder('price','ASC');

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $associatedProducts[] = $item;
        }

        $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
    }
    return $product->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
}
```

Using module:

1) Create `app/code/DSP/GroupedSimpleSort/registration.php` file:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'DSP_GroupedSimpleSort',
    __DIR__
);
```

2) Create `app/code/DSP/GroupedSimpleSort/etc/module.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="DSP_GroupedSimpleSort" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

3) Create `app/code/DSP/GroupedSimpleSort/etc/frontend/di.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" type="DSP\GroupedSimpleSort\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" />
</config>
```

4) Create `app/code/DSP/GroupedSimpleSort/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php` file:

```
<?php
namespace DSP\GroupedSimpleSort\Model\Product\Type;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped
{
    public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
    {
        if (!$product->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
            $associatedProducts = [];

            $this->setSaleableStatus($product);

            $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection(
                $product
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
                ['name', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id']
            )->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->addStoreFilter(
                $this->getStoreFilter($product)
            )->addAttributeToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
            );

            $collection->setOrder('price','ASC');

            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $associatedProducts[] = $item;
            }

            $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
        }
        return $product->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
    }
}
```

5) Run below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Genius Satish. Thank you so much. Can you advise how to do this without overriding core file... do I need to create a new module in app/code?

Comment: yes, you have to create new module for that.

Comment: @YorkieMagento check my updated comment.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you so much, appreciate the help.

Comment: I belive you have to debug your solution more its create issues when we add customer group prices for single qty.